# What permissions did the user permit my application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for Documentation on Seeing what Permissions the User Actually permitted the Application. I can use the "installed" field (/[UID]?fields=installed) to see if the app is installed, but it's only a boolean. With no information on the actual permissions allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use /[UID]/permissions to get the list of permissions.

e.g. https://graph.facebook.com/me/permissions

You can also limit by fields

Comment: thank you for the prompt answer. this is exactly what we needed. Still can't find the doc's page for it on developers.facebook... not that it matters, just why i placed the question here :)